# tc_calendar dates array exclude

Tags: php, arrays, date, calendar

I am using a calendar to select dates (http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php)

I have a page where user chooses a first date and based on that choice can choose a last date, meaning that he chooses all dates of the same day in that interval (first date until a last date). For example if he chooses for the first date: 06-09-2017 (Wednesday) he can choose for a last date only a wednesday. So I want to make the calendar only show wednesdays for this case.

To disable days in this script the code is:

```
$myCalendar->disabledDay("Sat");
```

So I made this code to find the day chose, and disable all the other days:

```
$mydate = '2018-07-03'; //first date

echo date('D', strtotime( $mydate));

$dia = date('D', strtotime( $mydate));
$datafim = '2018-07-31'; //last date

$days = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");

if(($key = array_search($dia, $days)) !== false) {
    unset($days[$key]);
}

require_once('calendar/tc_calendar.php');
$myCalendar = new tc_calendar("datend", true, false);
$myCalendar->setIcon("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
$myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");
$myCalendar->setYearInterval(2017, date('Y'));
$myCalendar->dateAllow($mydate, $datafim);
$myCalendar->setDateFormat('j F Y');
$myCalendar->startMonday(true);
foreach ($days as &$value) {
    "$myCalendar->disabledDay('".$value."');\n";
}

$myCalendar->writeScript();
```

I echo $myCalendar->disabledDay('".$value."');\n";
and it prints well all disable but it doesnt work,
Any help please?

Comment: what *doesnt work* please go into more detail

Comment: Why is this being concentrated as a string : `"$myCalendar->disabledDay('".$value."');\n";` shouldn't it be `$myCalendar->disabledDay($value);` unless you are running an eval() somwhere in the script.. And you shouldn't be doing an `eval()` so please dont use it

Comment: Thats right ! Sorry night brainer, sometimes obvious things dont work.

Comment: Glad you got that resolved. No problem happens to the best of us. GL!